# How to fully download a dataset in RDF via Socrata on data.nasa.gov?

Tags: rdf, socrata

I need to download all the dataset in RDF of ["Meteorite Landings"](https://data.nasa.gov/Space-Science/Meteorite-Landings/gh4g-9sfh) via data.nasa.gov.
But when I try to download, the file has only 500 instances.

How to fully download this dataset in RDF ?

Have you an example of script (with wget or curl) ?

Comment: csv seems to get everything, so perhaps there's a bug? I suggest contacting them directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found that I have to use the parameters limit/offset with a token. The token is generated when I declared the app in the portal of the nasa. 
So I resume :
GET https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.rdf?$offset=1&$limit=1
And add in the header http :
X-App-Token: YOUR_APP_TOKEN

And so with curl, I can upload all the files with this solution :

```
curl --header "X-App-Token: YOUR_APP_TOKEN" \
-X GET 'https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.rdf?$offset=[1-46000:500]&$limit=500' \
-o 'nasa.Meteorites.#1.rdf'
```